# encrypt/decode issue in Code Igniter 2.1.4

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

I have encrypted email Address like

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$encoded = $this->encrypt->encode('user_email_address');
```

In `codeigniter` Model.
And after that when I tried to decode, it does not show the correct data.

```
$this->encrypt->decode('user_email_address');
```

It shows like

```
Jts¹+…Ru\¼A·¾Àp¤c’áµSîÆKÃ†—l¿Ýƒ>ü«%c‚µ~SÔNÏÂŠÖä3; ñÑ
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set encryption key in config file?

Comment: Yes  $config['encryption_key'] = 'my-encryption-key';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use directly email  to decode

Use it as

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$encodedEmail = $this->encrypt->encode('user_email_address');

$myEmail = $this->encrypt->decode($encodedEmail);
```

Comment: Hi Naim Malek,                                                                                     $this->load->library('encrypt');
$encodedEmail = $this->encrypt->encode('test@gmail.com');
$this->session->set_userdata('login_encoded_emal', $encodedEmail);
 $useremail = $this->encrypt->decode($this->session->userdata('login_encoded_emal'));
  echo $useremail;

Comment: Any chance to be a server security issue? May server block encryption like that

Comment: Its secure,not any security issue. No server can't block encryption like this

Comment: You can accept this answer if it's working. so it can be useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

set encryption_key based on the algorithm used for encryption. 
eg. for AES-128, encryption key must be 128 bits or 16 bytes (characters) long.
Or you can create key in your function itself before calling encode() function like:

```
$key = $this->encryption->create_key(16);
```

for more details : refer https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html